# How do I get Entity Framework Code First Migrations to see my models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I made a new ASP.Net Web Application and enabled migrations on it. I ran `add-migration initial` and the `initial` migration does in fact have all the default tables for authentication (dbo.AspNetRoles, dbo.AspNetUserRoles, etc). However, when I create my own context and add an entity model to it, I can't get migrations to acknowledge that model. That is, when I run `add-migration added-watchedgame-model` I just get an "empty" migration file. So what am I doing wrong? Does my DbContext have to be referenced somehow? can Entity Framework only handle migrations for 1 dbcontext?

ReleaseDateMailerDBContext.cs:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using WebApplication4.Models;

namespace WebApplication4.DataAccess
{
    public class ReleaseDateMailerDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public ReleaseDateMailerDBContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

        public DbSet<WatchedGameModel> WatchedGameModelSet { get; set; }
    }
}
```

WatchedGameModel.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class WatchedGameModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1024)]
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool EmailSent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

"empty" migration file:

```
namespace ReleaseDateMailer.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class addedwatchedgamemodel : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think  you need to run `update-database` so the framework adds the table to the database.

Comment: @Ingenioushax gave it a shot, no luck.

Comment: you need to run the enable-migrations command to initialize code first migrations on the database

Comment: @pquest already did, that's how I got the dbo.AspNetRoles tables already

Comment: @AdamR.Grey : Do you mean AspNetRoles tables are created? in that case, do you created this new file `ReleaseDateMailerDBContext` and added the DBSet over there.
You have to look up for the file `ApplicationDbContext` there you have to update the new DBSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- With the built-in asp.net mvc project, a DbContext class (`ApplicationDbContext`) is already
  created!
- When you enter `enable-migrations`, a migration configuration class is created based on the dbcontext class that it finds.
- When you enter `add-migration "migrationname"`, That dbcontext class is what is checked for differences.

So all one has to do is, rather than making one's own class that derives from `DbContext`, use that one.

Answer (score 0):

"Batch Clean" may resolve your porblem.

It suggests that the EF tooling/assemblies are looking in a location other than the default build output location (typically /bin/Debug). The clean command also, incidentally, clears intermediary outputs.

To do a batch clean:

1. Select `Build` -> `Batch Build`
2. Click  `Select All`
3. Click  `Clean`

Close dialog, rebuild and re-attempt migration.

Answer (score 0):

While running the add-migration command your package manager console should be pointed to the project having your DBContext class (WebApplication4.DataAccess).
If you have migration in a different project than your web application project (suppose WebApplication4.Web) then you should run the following command:

```
add-migration "MigrationName" -projectName:WebApplication.DataAccess -startupProjectName:WebApplication4.Web
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: It's all one project for me. (gave it a shot anyway, no luck) Is that the issue, must I use more than one project?

Comment: @AdamR.Grey No. Its not mandatory for them to be in different projects. They can be in a single project.

Comment: @AdamR.Grey I mean context is in WebApplication4.DataAccess but migration is in ReleaseDateMailer.Migrations. Can you post your folder structure? Also did you enable migrations by typing in "enable-migrations" in package manager console.

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake, I changed the project's name at some point. My folder structure is the default web project structure... I'd post it, but I figured out what I was doing wrong, check out my answer.